# Launch Instrumentation tests from intent

Tags: android, firebase, testing, apk

I have a web app that is using Firebase FCM to communicate with my android device.

On receiving a certain data message through Firebase, I need android to run Instrumentation tests (such tests are run in a separate test application or "test APK" which is developed in the androidTest folder).

How can I make an Intent that will launch the test APK?

Comment: What do you mean by "test apk"? Can you show some example code? See [mcve] for tips about creating a code example.

Comment: Hi I just updated the question to clarify what I mean by test apk.  I'm referring to the separate test application that is used in instrumentation tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run instrumentation tests in response to an external stimulus like this.  Instrumentation tests are always driven through a JUnit test harness, which requires yet some other controlling process to kick them off using the `am instrument` command line program on the device.  This is typically Android Studio, which will install both your app APK and your test APK, then kick off the tests.  [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/) will also take both APKs kick off your tests on physical and virtual devices.

Comment: Can we kick off tests from main activity?